# WP url to get rss with full text of post

Tags: categories, rss

I need to curl a wordpress site and fetch in rss format:
1. all categories
2. for a category, all posts. They need to contain title and full body (not description).

given my site is somewpsite.com, how do I write the 2 URLs for above needs?

thank you.

Comment: You want to get a list of categories, or you want all posts regardless of category?

Answer (score 0):

Find an archive that displays what you want, and add /feed/ to the end

e.g. `/category/test` becomes `/category/test/feed`, `/` becomes `/feed/`, `/books/` becomes `/books/feed`

If you add /feed to the end of a single posts URL you will get a comment feed

You can also do `/feed/rss2` or `/feed/atom`

RSS feeds should contain a title and content, if an excerpt is shown rather than the full content, you should go to your reading settings and change the relevant option